# Does it matter how I setup test data when creating unit tests?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, tdd

I have a unit test similar to the code snippet below, it should check that the AddUser method only allows unique emails.

My question is around the `Arrange` part of this unit test, I use existing system code to setup the first user (class `UserLogic`), this is so that I have a user in context to perform the next parts of the test (`Act` and `Arrange`).

```
[Fact]
public void CheckUniqueEmail()
{
    var context = new DbContext(); //EF Core in memory db

    //Arrange
    UserLogic userlogic = new UserLogic(context);
    User user = new User('test@test.com');

    userlogic.AddUser(user);

    //Act
    UserLogic userlogicNew = new UserLogic(context);
    User userNew = new User('test@test.com');

    bool result = userlogicNew.AddUser(userNew); //result should be false since this email has already been used

    //Assert
    Assert.False(result);
}
```

However, I have seen this done in two ways: The first is as I have done above. The second would be to insert data directly into context, as in the next example

```
[Fact]
public void CheckUniqueEmail()
{
var context = new DbContext(); //EF Core in memory db

//Arrange
context.Users.Add(new User({Email='test@test.com'}))
context.SaveChanges();    

//Act
UserLogic userlogicNew = new UserLogic(context);
User userNew = new User('test@test.com');

bool result = userlogicNew.AddUser(userNew); //result should be false since this email has already been used

//Assert
Assert.False(result);
}
```

Based on the foregoing, **does matter the way I arrange the data for the unit tests? Which one of the two approaches do you think is appropriated for unit tests?**

Comment: Are you inserting data into an actual database here? That seems fragile.

Comment: Exactly. Can you mock DBContext? So that you adapt its behaviour to the needs of the unit test?

Comment: Forgot to mention, i am using EFCore in memory database for testing

Comment: Then #2. Load the preconditions directly on the mocked layer. #1 is assuming that the same method you are testing, is working fine :-). That's too much assumption. If by any reason `addUser` is compromised, it will compromise the whole test.

Comment: @Laiv - right.  The key principle here is that, as far as you can reasonably arrange it, *one problem in the code should cause one test to fail*.  If you're depending on your production code to set up data for a test, then the test can fail if that production code is broken, too.  If you need to do a lot of setup and doing it via the database is more verbose (or your database design changes a lot), consider adding utilities for making it easier as part of the testing code.

Comment: You should also consider testing using SQLite in-memory mode.  It integrates nicely with EF Core: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/, and according to Microsoft, unlike in-memory testing, it will always behave like a relational database.

Comment: that sir! is an integration test!

Comment: @Eternal21 unfortunately there are differences between mssql and sqlite sql syntax. its not a good test to substitute one for the other

Comment: Shameless plug of my answer to a very similar question on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22691703/352176

Comment: @Ewan I just finished a project where I used SQLite testing for a code that uses MSSQL database i production, and had no issues (which is why Microsoft recommends it).  Remember - you are testing against Entity Framework, which makes the tests database agnostic.

Comment: @Eternal21 I have had to refactor tests like yours because they fail or report false success. There are plenty of potholes for you to hit down the road

Comment: @Ewan I don't know what your tests were doing, but mine test against EF DbContext, so using SQLite method was the right way to go.  You'll find many more 'potholes' using in-memory testing.  For example eager loading LINQ behavior will be different (with in-memory, child records are included by default, where testing with actual database you will need to explicitly call 'Include' function).

Comment: @Eternal21 If I remember right my specific problem was with dates. Sqlite doesn't have a date type. Perhaps if you only ever use linq statements to query EF will save you from problems. But remember EF supports random sql commands, sprocs and the like.

Answer (score 3):

How you set up test data is important, and I'd argue both versions are suboptimal.

Every method or class you write has a contract, whether explicit (by documentation for instance) or implicit (by what the code actually does). This contract is important, because it describes what the clients, i.e. the code that uses your class, should expect when it uses it. Unit testing is a method to programmatically document the contract of the code under test, in a way that it ensures that the behaviour is the same even if the implementation changes.

An important characteristic of unit tests is that they want the code under test (CUT) to be **isolated** from other code. This means you have to be very careful when the CUT has dependencies. If it uses a dependency which has a different reason to change than itself (this is what *responsibility* means in the single responsibility principle), you'll usually have an abstraction to isolate these two. This abstraction itself has a contract, and in unit testing, you assume that the abstraction on which you depend will behave according to its contract. In unit tests, this generally means that this dependency will be *mocked*, and you will pilot the mock to behave in a certain way.

Back to your example now. You are unit testing the `UserLogic` class. It has two dependencies that I can see: `User` and `DbContext`. I don't have enough context to know what `User` is, but I'll assume it is some sort of value object. In that case, it is fine to use it directly.
`DbContext` is a different beast. It seems to be an implementation of some sort of persistence. It definitely has a different reason to change than `UserLogic`, which means it should be abstracted by an interface of some sort. I'll assume you already have one which is called `Context`.

Therefore, I can assume the implementation of `UserLogic.AddUser` looks like something like this:

```
public boolean AddUser(User user) {
  if (context.HasUser(user)) {
    return false;
  }

  context.AddUser(user);
  context.SaveChanges();
  return true;
}
```

The outcome that you want to unit test is as follow: If the `User` has already been added to the `context`, you want to ensure the `Context` hasn't changed (no new users were added, nor were the changes saved).

The description of the outcome described pretty much exactly how the unit test should look. What you want to arrange is that the `context` already has a specific `User`. What you want to act on is `AddUser`. What you want to assert is that the `User` was not added, and the `Context` was not saved. Therefore, your unit test looks like this (in Java, I'm not too familiar with C# testing libraries):

```
@Test
public void givenContextAlreadyHasTheUser_whenAddUser_thenTheUserIsNotAddedASecondTime() {
  // Arrange
  Context context = mock(Context.class);
  User user = new User("test@test.com");
  UserLogic userLogic = new UserLogic(context);
  given(context.HasUser(user)).willReturn(true);

  // Act
  userLogic.AddUser(user);

  // Assert
  verify(context, never()).AddUser(any());
  verify(context, never()).SaveChanges();
}
```

As a user of the `UserLogic` class, I can refer to this test to know exactly what the contract of `AddUser` describes in the case where the `User` is already added to the context, which is what I'm looking for in unit tests.

Comment: Few extraneous notes in no particular order: I try to follow the `givenX_whenY_thenZ` when naming my tests because I believe `CheckUniqueEmail` is not descriptive enough. A class named `UserLogic` raises a flag in my head (as does `Context`). I consider the `boolean` return to be a different outcome that what the test I posted asserts, which means I'd expect a second test with the same `Arrange` section, but which now asserts that the return of the function is `false`.

Answer (score 2):

You should wrap your entity framework calls in a repository class which implements an interface.

You can then inject a mock repository into your userlogic class. with the appropriate already existing user  and avoid having a database dependency.

An alternative for where you have complicated data dependencies is to use database snapshots to create an entirely new database populated with dummy data for a single test

```
IUserRepo
{
    User GetUser(string id);
    void AddUser(User user);
}

MyTest()
{
    //set up mock with the framework of your choice
    IUserRepo repo = new MockUserRepo();
    repo.GetUser = ('test@test.com') => { return new User('test@test.com'); };

    var userLogic = new UserLogic(repo)
    var user = new User('test@test.com');
    var actual = userLogic.AddUser(user);
    Assert.IsFalse(actual);
}
```